# Chrome not asking for allow location in server

Tags: javascript, asp.net, geolocation

I have 2 text boxes in which I am getting latitude and longitude on page load. Everything is working fine on localhost but on server side allow location popup is not coming. Below is my code working perfectly on local.[Image is for example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YlnKN.png)

```
    <script>
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success);
    }

    function success(position) {
        document.getElementById("lat").value = position.coords.latitude;
        document.getElementById("long").value = position.coords.longitude;
    }
</script>

<body>
    <form  runat="server">

    <div>   
        Lat:  <asp:TextBox ID="lat" runat="server"></asp:TextBox><br />
        Long: <asp:TextBox ID="long" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

Comment: I don't understand the problem. Please attach an image of it.

Comment: any error in html console ?

Comment: Image already attached https://i.stack.imgur.com/YlnKN.png

Comment: No Error I am not getting https://i.stack.imgur.com/YlnKN.png this allow your location prompt. on server

Comment: you only added success callback try error callback also and print in console. and share that error `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success,e=>{console.log(e)});`

Comment: you need allow one time for location api for that domain, second time onwards it will not ask

Comment: Yeah I removed try error callback but this code is working perfectly in my asp website on local host. The problem is on server.

Comment: Not even asking for one time on server

Comment: IIRC, Chrome has recently changed how they handle these permission popups - sites can not keep on nagging users until they grant the permission any more, but Chrome will stop asking after the user declined once. Go check the settings for the site in question, and see what is configured there regarding this permission.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution. My website has no SSL certificate and when I converted it to https it is working fine on server too.